# Can we use XML DSL in quarkus+Camel application

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I have created a XML DSL based camel application which is deployed in redhat fuse. Now, I want to develop and run the same application in quarkus. My routes are not getting initiated in quarkus.

It shows below message in the log.

Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started

What additional configuration should I make so that the routers are detected and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no it is not possible to use spring/blueprint xml files in camel-quarkus.

You can define routes in xml, like in this example https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/tree/master/examples/timer-log-xml but if you need to define beans, etc. you need to do it programmatically with CDI

Comment: I am open to use any technology to route the exel files and process it. I got to know that Kafka can also serve this purpose. Any pointers to achieve this using Kafka : simple steps: read new files, create json documents, insert into mongo collection

Comment: it is very hard to give any advice without any reference to the project and what it actually does so I'd recommend to create a simple GitHub project with what you ahve as today and we can give some advice.

Comment: Thanks Luca. Requirement is to just read the arriving files in the specified folder location and convert the data into json format. I was able to convert my spring DSL into Java DSL manually and it works now.

Comment: In quarkus camel, I have observed that application gets halted sometime, it doesn't process the request. I had to hit enter in my quarkus console to trigger the processing of my request [it happen sometime]. Any clue on that ?

Comment: never had such issue